# Imnitializing a prmitive array - corrupting other arrays

Tags: xcode, arrays, matrix, initialization

I am using primitive array type in xcode. Example:

```
int matrix [10][10];
```

I am also using a simple loop to initialise the array

```
for(int x=0;x<=10;x++)
  for(int y=0;y<=1;0y++)
     matrix[x][y] = 0;
```

I initialize sevreal matrices in this manner throughout the code.  I noticed at times after the  initialization is performed, an array that was prviously initialized or updated now contains garbage.  Is there a simpler way to initialize an array of this type.  And/Or why does this seem to corrupt other arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

int myArray[10][10] = {};

THis will create the array and initialize all occurrences to 0;

Answer (score 1):

Your array has 10 positions in both dimensions, but your loops go up to eleven.

Try

```
for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
  for(int y = 0; y < 10; y++)
     matrix[x][y] = 0;
```

Notice the use of the **lesser than** comparator instead of **lesser than or equal to**.

Comment: Sorry.  THe example I provided above is just an example to drive the point,  I see my error, but it does not relate to the "garbage" in the matrix values.

Comment: You should update your question to show the actual code that you're having trouble with.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you aren't declaring different variables for different matrices and are by mistake overwriting them.

Comment: Thanks. The matrices are unique.  I checked the output.  If I had been overwriting, the different matrices would contain sonme of the same values.

Answer (score 0):

Try It...

```
matrix=[[NSArray alloc]init];
```

Comment: I get an error that says 'Array type 'int[10][10] is not assignable

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause of corruption like you're seeing (provided that you haven't made the error that @Renan notes), is that you're expecting a stack pointer to exist outside of its scope. You can't, for instance, `return matrix` to a caller, since the stack frame it's created on will vanish.

Also, since you're allocating on the stack, you need to be careful of your matrix size. If it gets too large, then you'll get stack corruption. 100 ints is generally fine if you're not recursing deeply, but keep in mind the [stack limits](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/CreatingThreads/CreatingThreads.html):

- OS X main thread: 8MB
- iOS main thread: 1MB
- All secondary threads: 512kB

That's the whole stack (all frames, not just the current frame).